# Same message posted to multiple queues from JMS code ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Hi I am trying to post the same message to multiple queues based on some data condition.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (msginstanceof TextMessage) {

       if(<data check1>){
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("inbound.1");
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        log.info("Preparing to send to queue1");
        producer.send(msg);
        log.info("Message sent to queue1");

      }
      if(<data check 2>){
         Destination destination = session.createQueue("Queue2");
         MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
         log.info("Preparing to send to Queue2");
         producer.send(msg);
         log.info("Message sent to Queue2");
      }
```

But i dont know when i send the message to the first queue will there be a message left to be sent to the second queue? the message is captured in a onMessage method which is part of javax.jms.MessageListener class.

I am testing this out too but wondering if there is something obvious that i missed.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it works just fine.
The two messages will get different message ids but should otherwise be very similar.